# Clipping will be lost on roundtrip to Tiny

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, shapes, clipping-mask

I'm trying to open a client SVG format image into illustrator, however I get this message "Clipping will be lost on roundtrip to Tiny" which means some parts of the image aren't clipped to where they should be. How can this be resolved easily?  (see attached image)

[image: Image shows shapes clipping over the area they should be.]

Comment: Can you post the XML information in your question?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ? if so , how ?